# ln(x+y)=ln(x)+ln(y)

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

The question demands an answer to when ln(x+y) can be considered to equal ln(x)+ ln(y) and we are asked to use contour to prove this but the concept of contour does not entirely make sense to me. Anyways the answer is for y=x/(x-1) for x>1 how do we reach this using contour?

Comment: Hint: $\ln (x)+\ln (y)=\ln (xy)$.  Not sure what you mean by "contour".

Comment: I suspect "contour" was being used in the sense of a (level?) curve.  In any case the relationship between $x$ and $y$ works out just as the answer you stated (for $x \gt 1$, at least).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT**: Observe $$\begin{align}\ln(x + y) &= \ln(x) + \ln(y)\\ &= \ln(xy) \tag{Product Log Rule}\\ \implies x + y &= xy \tag{One-to-one property} \end{align}$$

Can you figure out what to do from here?

Answer (score 1):

$$\ln(x+y) = \ln x+\ln y$$
Use the Product Rule.
$$\implies \ln(x+y) = \ln(x\cdot y)$$
Remove the natural log from both sides.
$$\implies x+y = xy$$
$$x = xy-y \implies x = y(x-1) \implies y = \frac{x}{x-1};x>1$$
Very clearly, $x$ cannot be $0$ (incorrect) or $1$ ($y$ becomes undefined), so our domain is $x>1$.